# Motivation of an Open Set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

What is the motivation of an open set in a metric space? I understand how open balls are motivated, but I do not understand why one would want to define an interior point or an open set.

I am only talking about metric spaces, not topological spaces.

Comment: It turns out that open balls are important in metric space; but many of the same proofs go through when you use open sets and these satisfy a simple set of axioms aka the axioms for a topological space.

Comment: Eventually something is interesting because it is interesting; you can't go down the motivational rabbit hole forever. In this case I'd say that open sets are interesting because they help you understand limits and continuity, which are already at the bottom of the rabbit hole in some sense.

Comment: Regarding your edit: the big plus of open sets rather than open balls is that they generalize to strictly topological notions. For example, the topological definition of continuity does *not* let you say that the preimage of an open ball is an open ball.

Comment: Open sets are interesting because they express all the topological information given by the metric, and readily generalise to non-metrisable spaces.

Comment: Well... [you could have invented topology](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://luis.impa.br/aulas/lectures/inventingTopology.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj2ouvR3PPXAhVKC5AKHbPgCsAQFggnMAA&usg=AOvVaw2I642rXmjLfzrbbW16KxKx).

Answer (score 1):

Open sets give us a notion of a set $A$ that's "locally convex" - i.e., for any point $x\in A$ there's a small ball of points in $A$ around $x$. Equivalently, for some $\epsilon>0$, the ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ (centered at $x$, with radius $\epsilon$) is a subset of $A$. This is a useful idea when we're trying to define a derivative of a function; we need to take a limit approaching $x$ from an arbitrary direction, so there needs to be a ball around each point we define the derivative on. Open sets are then a required part of the definition of a derivative.

Comment: I think the point is: why not just talk locally the whole time instead of talking through local means about this global object.

Comment: Open sets qua analysis kinda are the sets such that you can always talk locally, though. At least for elementary analysis; and that seems to be the setting OP is thinking in. I'm trying to think of a more interesting analytically motivated example though.